# HTML5 FileReader api portrait orientation issue

Tags: html, orientation, filereader

I am trying to show an image from user's computer using HTML5 FileReader api. Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xEzcZ/.

The problem is, when I try to upload an image with portrait orientation, the image is "flipped" when I place it in the IMG tag. If I open the same image in Preview on my Mac, it opens up correctly. Is there a way that I can show that image in correct orientation using FileReader as well?

```
//js
$(function(){

    $('input').on('change', function(e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            $('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    });
});

//html
<input type="file" name="photo" />

<img class="photo" src="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the orientation of the original image is wrong but your Mac is automatically fixing it while the minimal javaScript code you have here has no way of doing this. For this one image you can fix it but it's a little convoluted - here's an article: 
http://www.brianculler.com/golbhet/2009/05/26/portrait-image-orientation-in-mac-os-x-and-how-to-fix-it/

If you need to prevent this scenario for users you may want to simply add some code that allows the user to change the uploaded image's orientation from your app.